# Locust method for some setup before each task

Tags: python, performance-testing, locust

Is there some method (ideally for a `User` class) or event or other way in Locust to execute some setup code before each task?

---

What I have looked into:

- there are some useful events, unfortunately none like `on_task_start`
- there are some useful methods like `test_start`, but unfortunately none like `task_start`
- I could use the `wait_time()` method on a `User` class, but that is an ugly work around, and the method is not called before the first task of each `User` instance.

Answer (score 1):

You can add custom events to locust see:
https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/api.html#EventHook%20class

update:

```
class DbTaskSet(TaskSet):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def execute_next_task(self):
        myevent.fire()
        super().execute_next_task()
```

Comment: Thanks @Muhammeed Tanir (+1), that gives me the class to implement a custom event. However, I still do not know where to locate the code (in this case the `event.fire()` to trigger the event before each task execution.

Comment: a quick workaround would be fire the event in tasks that you wrote, but i think it would be better to overwrite execute_task method which is under task.py . Updated the answer